# List of Future-Instances

Tags: java, concurrency, guava, future, executorservice

I'd like to replace a List of Future-Instances with something more performant. Currently I'm traversing a tree and submit a Callable to determine the number of descendant-or-self nodes for each node in the tree. I'm saving the Future instance in a List and then get the appropriate node count from the List once required:

```
try {
    assert mIndex + 1 < mDescendants.size();
    mItem =
        Item.BUILDER.set(mAngle, mExtension, mIndexToParent).setParentDescendantCount(
                mParDescendantCount).setDescendantCount(mDescendants.get(mIndex + 1).get()).build();
} catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    LOGWRAPPER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

The sad thing is that the axis which is making use of the List has to wait until all Future instances have been submitted. Furthermore it doesn't scale beyond main memory limits :-/

Maybe Google Guava and ListenableFuture is the right thing to use.

Edit: Now I think I'll actually build something with a PropertyChangeListener where Futures are added to a list whenever a Future is fired. Then I initiate a CountDownLatch to 1 and call countDown() everytime a new Future is added to the List. Something like:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if (mDescendants.size() > 0) {
        return doHasNext();
    } else {
        try {
            mLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            LOGWRAPPER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return doHasNext();
    }
}
```

then in doHasNext():

```
try {
    assert mIndex + 1 < mDescendants.size();
    mItem =
        Item.BUILDER.set(mAngle, mExtension, mIndexToParent).setParentDescendantCount(
                mParDescendantCount).setDescendantCount(mDescendants.get(mIndex + 1).get()).build();
    mLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
} catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    LOGWRAPPER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

and the Listener:

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent paramEvent) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(paramEvent);

    if ("descendants".equals(paramEvent.getPropertyName())) {
        mDescendants.add((Future<Integer>) paramEvent.getNewValue());
        mLatch.countDown();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it works, it's too late and I mistrust the way I would use the CountDownLatch (haven't tested the above code).

Edit: Just in case someone is interested. Instead of the CountDownLatch and a List I now simply used a BlockingQueue in conjunction with the implementation of a PropertyChangeListener, which seems to be a good, "clean" solution.

regards,

Johannes

Comment: I don't understand much from the code you submitted (what does Item.BUILDER do?), but, if your List is too big to fit in memory, a possible solution is to rewrite your code to work with iterables / iterators instead, and process your items on the fly. Guava has many utility methods to help with this in com.google.common.collect.Iterables and com.google.common.collect.Iterators.

Comment: "feature instance" -> You mean Future instance, right?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use a [completion service](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html)? Once submitted, it'll process the first future to complete...

Comment: No, I need them in order, that's why I think it's the best way to use the observer pattern and a BlockingQueue. It's just a pipe or something and it's clearly faster. Now I just have to replace another bottleneck where I'm firing changes when all items have been produced, which is a waste of time.

Comment: If you need them to complete in a specific order, aren't they just serial? ie, why not just wait for each future in turn? the affect would be the same as using an observer no? and be simpler..? I'd suggest that submitting jobs shouldn't be a huge overhead, it'll most likely be outweighed by the wait for each job to complete.

Comment: It seems to make a huge difference for larger trees (especially 1MB and above -- if one might think of it as a larger tree). It clearly seems to scale better, because even for about 2000 nodes the traversal and submitting of the tree seems to last about 2 to 3 seconds, but I haven't benchmarked it. As such a kind of pipelined approach speeds up the whole process :-)

Comment: do you mean the call to submit takes 2 seconds on the object construction/pre-work needed to be able to submit?

Comment: No, the whole iteration through the tree with submitting the callables for each node.

Comment: I meant to say "do you mean the call to submit takes 2 seconds OR the object construction/pre-work needed to be able to submit?" in the last comment. If it takes 2-3 seconds to sumbit the full list, it'll start processing immediately after the first submit, so I'm unclear what your problem is I'm afraid.